# CSS linear gradient not showing up in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Our designer created a mockup of our frontend using HTML and CSS. However, when I copy the code to my rails app, some of it is not working properly.

Below is the CSS that is failing:

```
#login h1 {

  font-size:17px;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding:5px 12px;
  margin-bottom:0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #77659E 35%, #5A4B7A 77%);
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;

}
```

It's suppose to show a purple colour as the background but it's not. My guess is linear-gradient is not getting picked up. Everything else in the CSS seems to work fine.

I'm using Rails 3.1. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've tried on chrome and firefox. Both failed.

Comment: there is an error with the syntax I guess... try to generate css codes using this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your designer is most likely using [prefix free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/), to fix it just add the prefixes:

```
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #77659E 35%, #5A4B7A 77%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #77659E 35%, #5A4B7A 77%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #77659E 35%, #5A4B7A 77%);
```

You will need to use a [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) if you want to target IE

Comment: Yes. It's the prefix! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unprefixed [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient) property does not work anywhere yet.

You must add `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, and `-o-` vendor prefixes to make it work in five major browsers (IE only 10+, though).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fEB3m/