# Rails 6 Gradient will not take up the whole page no matter WHAT I do

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, background

I am having an extremly frustrating problem with Rails.  If I use a regular HTML page with no rails the gradient works properly. If I put it into my Rails app it will NOT work right no matter what I do.  It will either take up only the center of the screen, the bottom or it decides all on its own to repeat at the bottom?  What am I doing wrong?

What I am TRYING to do is simply put this gradient at the login screen ONLY.   So Devise/new.html.haml

Here is my gradient code:

```
.login-bg {

    background: rgb(236,240,241);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ecf0f1",endColorstr="#234a59",GradientType=1);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    heigh: 100%;
}
```

If I put .login-bg at the top of the new.html.haml it will give me this:
[image]

If I change the name of the gradient css to html, body { code } it will give me this:
[image]

I tried putting it right on the HTML tag and if I do that it does this:
[image]

Where and how am I supposed to implement this simple gradient and have it take up the WHOLE SCREEN not these zones?  Again if I put this in a normal HTML page and put the div at the top with the class of login-bg it works PROPERLY.  So I don't know if it is Rails, Bootstrap  3 or WHAT in the world is causing this awful behavior.

I couldn't find one single search result ANYPLACE that has this information.  All I could find was people using background images.  This shouldn't be this hard.

If anyone wants to see anything else please let me know.
I assume this is a matter of a Rails way of doing this and I just don't know what it is.
Its hard to believe there is NO DOCUMENTATION for this ANYPLACE but I couldn't find ANYTHING on this subject at all.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.
Scott

Comment: I found solution in this post.. [Rails Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050941/13401546)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out.  I added the additional -ms- and -o- prefixes and that did NOTHING at all.  I left them in anyway since that post that @Sagmar recommended it.

So in the end this was my CSS code:

```
.login-bg {

    background: rgb(236,240,241);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(236,240,241,1) 0%, rgba(35,74,89,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ecf0f1",endColorstr="#234a59",GradientType=1);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

To get it to work I had to put the .login-bg on both the HTML tag and the BODY tag for the gradient to take the entire area.  Have no idea WHY I had to do that or why that wouldn't make it look like 2 different zones like the pictures I originally posted but I tried it and it DID WORK!

This app use HAML in case it looks funny.

```
!!!
%html.login-bg
  %head
    %meta{name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}
    %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'FILTERtrak'
    %meta{name: 'description', content: "#{content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : 'FILTERtrak'}"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    
  %body.login-bg
    = link_to search_path do
      - if user_signed_in?
        = image_tag @company.logo.url(:medium), alt: @company.name, style: "max-height: 200px;"
      - else
        = image_tag 'logo.png', alt: "FILTERtrak", style: 'max-width: 400px;'
    - if flash
      .row
        .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
          = render 'layouts/messages'
    .container
      = yield
```

For STRAIT HTML you would do it like so:
Example only shows the 2 relevant tags:

```
<html class="login-bg"> 

<body class="login-bg>
```

UPDATE:
I also added this to my CSS to make it not change if you scroll down:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I added it to my above CSS

Here is the screenshot:
[image]